# How can show $\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+u^a}\,du\right)<1-1/\sqrt{2}$

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

I was working on a problem and reduced it to showing the following inequality: ‎‎
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+u^a}\,du\right)<1-1/\sqrt{2};\quad a>0.$$
Your suggestion?

Comment: Is no more conditions about $a$?

Comment: It even seems that there is a tighter bound $\approx 0.3$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That tighter bound is $1-1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @mickep. You are perfectly right ! Thanks.

Comment: No, that does not look correct for any $a$, and in particular not for $a$ close to zero...

Comment: Indeed, for large $a$ you get the bound by $1/2$. But that does not solve your problem as stated above.

Comment: I must show the above function is increasing in $a$. what is your idea?

Comment: If $a>0$ goes to zero the expression on the left side goes to infinity, so the inequality can't be correct.

Comment: @user213008 Well, the integral goes to $\sqrt{2}$ so it is not that easy... Graphically, the inequality is true.

Comment: If $a$ goes to 0, then the second bracket is zero.

Comment: huuh, this is quiet though (and interesting) (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint:

$\sqrt{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\ge \dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}$

but it is for $<\dfrac{1}{2}$

edit 1:

$\sqrt{\dfrac{1+u^a}{2}}>\dfrac{1+u^{\frac{a}{2}}}{2}$

now you can integral this function and go further which shouldn't be difficult .

edit 2:

lemma: for $0 \le x \le 1, \sqrt{1+x} \ge 1+(\sqrt2-1)x$

square both sides we have $(\sqrt2-1)x(1-x) \ge 0$ which is true.

so we have $\sqrt{1+u^a} \ge 1+(\sqrt2-1)u^a$

then you get the better result.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: (+1) This answer seems to solve the problem as it was originally stated. Now that OP change it to have the optimal constant, it has become more difficult...